# Is it possible to disable the interlocutor's video in Skype?

Tags: windows, skype

Is it possible to disable all videos for anybody in the call in Skype when in a videoconference?

The motivation is to reduce the network usage. I use Skype on Microsoft Windows.

Comment: @DavidPostill What's unclear?

Comment: Your meaning of the word interlocutor (a person who takes part in a dialogue or conversation.). Do you mean your own video, the video of the the person currently speaking, the video of the person who set up the call, all video for anybody on the call?

Comment: @DavidPostill all videos for anybody in the call